# doctrine2: different way of querying, different results

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

Can someone explain, why I get different results?

```
$user = new UserEn();
$user->setName("test");
$em->persist($user);

$result1 = $em->find('UserEn', 'test');

$result2 = $em->getRepository('UserEn')->findBy(array('name'=>'test'));

$q = $em->createQuery('select u from UserEn u where u.name = :name');
$q->setParameter('name', 'test');
$result3 = $q->getResult();
```

Only $result1 holds $user, which is what I expected, and the others are null. What's wrong? (Please don't say that I need to call $em->flush(); )

Comment: `$result2` and `$result3` should return an array, I think ...

Comment: Include your entity code + mapping

Answer (score 1):

Because Doctrine can't figure out that you are specifically requesting an `User` object which has name property set to `test` from the query, it queries the DB(ignoring caching mechanism),  map resultset to entity object, load them in entity manager and return the array of entity object[s] if any data found. So there is no involvement of entity manager here. Things would be different if you used `find($id)` instead of `findBy()` because now Doctrine will check entity manager first, query DB if not found.

Answer (score 0):

#### $result2

This returns an array that holds all entities with `test` as name:

```
$result2 = $em->getRepository('UserEn')->findBy(array('name'=>'test'));
```

In order to get only one record you should use `findOneBy` instead of `findBy`:

```
$result2 = $em->getRepository('UserEn')->findOneBy(array('name'=>'test'));
```

#### $result3

In the `$result3` you should call `$q->getSingleResult()` instead of `$q->getResult()`:

```
$result3 = $q->getSingleResult();
```

Comment: When I tested it with findOneBy, I received: No result was found for query although at least one row was expected. Implying that 'findBy'  finds also no object. With getSingleResult: No result was found for query although at least one row was expected. Also meaning that 'getResult' would find no object either.

Comment: What's funny is "$result1 = $em->find('UserEn', 'test');" works. $result1: 
  
  UserEn object {
  *User*name => (string) test
  *User*regist => null
  *User*con => (int) 0
  *User*last => DateTime object {
    date => (string) 1990-01-01 00:00:00
    timezone_type => (int) 3
    timezone => (string) Europe/Berlin
  }

Comment: @user1592714, if you used `$em->find('UserEn', 'test')` and it works... looks like the `name` is the primary key. :s